# webdriver display size in PhantomJS

Tags: selenium, webdriver, phantomjs

Im looking for a way to set the display size (not viewport) in PhantomJS. I found a piece of [code](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/phantomjs/rooLTvR7gEU/qdUr3HFANokJ) for doing this directly with PhantomJS, but I haven't found a way to do this with the webdriver bindings.

Comment: Can you explain your use of the word "viewport" ?   Do you just mean "window size"?

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this is WebDriver:

```
public static void setWindowPosition(String handle, int width, int height, int fleft, int ftop) {
    driver.switchTo().window( handle ).manage().window().setPosition( new Point(fleft, ftop) );
    driver.switchTo().window( handle ).manage().window().setSize( new Dimension( width, height) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C#, I use this line of code in Selenium Webdriver:

```
Driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(1366, 768);
```